# Reusing the same command function for multiple click commands in python

Tags: python, click

Consider the following toy example:

```
from pydantic import BaseModel
from model.dataset_model import DatasetModel


@click.group(chain=True)
@click.version_option()
def main() -> None:
    pass


@main.result_callback()
def run(parameters: Dict[str, BaseModel]) -> None:
    print(parameters)    

@main.command("training")
@click.option(
    "--name",
    type=str,
    required=True,
    help="The name of the dataset",
)
@click.option(
    "--root-path",
    type=str,
    required=True,
    help="The root of the dataset on S3 storage",
)
@click.option(
    "--split",
    type=float,
    required=True,
    help="The split of the dataset",
)
def get_training_set(name: str, root_path: str, split: float):
    return {"training": DatasetModel(name=name, root_path=root_path, split=split)}


@main.command("test")
@click.option(
    "--name",
    type=str,
    required=True,
    help="The name of the dataset",
)
@click.option(
    "--root-path",
    type=str,
    required=True,
    help="The root of the dataset on S3 storage",
)
@click.option(
    "--split",
    type=float,
    required=True,
    help="The split of the dataset",
)
def get_test_set(name: str, root_path: str, split: float):
    return {"test": DatasetModel(name=name, root_path=root_path, split=split)}


@main.command("validation")
@click.option(
    "--name",
    type=str,
    required=True,
    help="The name of the dataset",
)
@click.option(
    "--root-path",
    type=str,
    required=True,
    help="The root of the dataset on S3 storage",
)
@click.option(
    "--split",
    type=float,
    required=True,
    help="The split of the dataset",
)
def get_validation_set(name: str, root_path: str, split: float):
    return {"validation": DatasetModel(name=name, root_path=root_path, split=split)}


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

As one can see, the commands for `training`, `test` and `validation` all do the same thing. I am wondering, if there is some option to reuse the same function for different click commands.
Something like the following (which does not work):

```
@main.command("training")
@main.command("test")
@main.command("validation")
@click.option(
    "--name",
    type=str,
    required=True,
    help="The name of the dataset",
)
@click.option(
    "--root-path",
    type=str,
    required=True,
    help="The root of the dataset on S3 storage",
)
@click.option(
    "--split",
    type=float,
    required=True,
    help="The split of the dataset",
)
def get_dataset(name: str, root_path: str, split: float):
    cmd = click.get_command_name() # some way to get the current command
    return {cmd : DatasetModel(name=name, root_path=root_path, split=split)}
```